# Uniform convergence of $x^k\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I have the following question: Consider the sequence
$$
f_k(x)=x^k\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x)
$$
Defined on the interval $(0,1)$. The question is, does it converge uniformly on $(0,1$).

Now, I think I have a proof that the answer is no, but a professor of mine claims that it does, so: Where is my mistake?

My argument is as follows: Let $b_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$. It is well-known that $f_k$ converges uniformly if and only if:
$$
||
f_k
||_{(0,1)}\rightarrow
0
$$
Since obviously, $f_k$ converges pointwise to $0$.

However, $
||
f_k
||_{(0,1)}
\geq
f_n(b_n)=(1-\frac{1}{n})^n\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}(1-\frac{1}{n}))\rightarrow
\frac{1}{e}
>
0
$.

Clearly, this implies $
||
f_k
||_{(0,1)}\not\rightarrow
0
$

So, is anything wrong with this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the argument of the sine function is $\pi x/2$ and not $\pi x$?  Otherwise the sequence fails to converge uniformly for the same reason that the sequence $x^n$ fails to converge uniformly on $(0,1)$.

Comment: It is $\pi/2$ int the original question. But now I realise this makes the question pointless.  (Since its now it's obvious convergence is not uniform, right?). I guess he meant, $\pi$ in the argument, then he might be right.

Comment: Anyway, in the caso the argument is $\pi$, then the convergence is uniform, but how do you show this?

Comment: I've posted a solution to address your question in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sequence of interest is $x^n\sin(\pi x/2)$, your analysis correctly shows that the sequence fails to uniformly converge on $(0,1)$ for the same reason that the sequence $x^n$ fails to converge uniformly on $(0,1)$.

However, if $f_n(x)=x^n\sin(\pi x)$ instead, then we can show that $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $0$ for  $x\in [0,1]$.

Note, that $f_n'(x)=nx^{n-1}\sin(\pi x)+\pi x^n \cos(\pi x)$.  The maximum value of $f_n(x)$ occurs at $x=x^*$ such that

$$n(x^*)^{n-1}\sin(\pi x^*) +\pi (x^*)^n \cos(\pi x^*)=0$$

But for $x=x^*$, we see that for $0<x^*<1$

$$\begin{align}
\max f(x)&= f(x^*)\\\\
& = x^*(n)^n\sin(\pi x^*(n))\\\\
&=-\frac\pi n (x^*)^{n+1}\cos(\pi x^*)\\\\
&\le \frac\pi n
\end{align}$$

and the convergence is uniform on $[0,1]$.